# X-Editable - typeshead version (?) conflict

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, x-editable

I'm using the x-editable as follows:

```
<a id="manager" href="#"  data-name="ManagerId" data-type="typeaheadjs" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Input manager"></a>
```

Everything is started with js code (taken from docs sample):

```
$('#manager').editable({
    value: 'ru',
    typeahead: {
        name: 'country',
        local: [
        { value: 'ru', tokens: ['Russia'] },
        { value: 'gb', tokens: ['Great Britain'] },
        { value: 'us', tokens: ['United States'] }
        ],
        template: function (item) {
            return item.tokens[0] + ' (' + item.value + ')';
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works unless typeahead 0.9.3 is referenced. If I update typeahead up to 0.10.2, the autocomplete box is not visible (**Local is replaced with Source of course**). How can can I get typeahd 0.10.2 to work? I don't want to use both version on the same site. X-Editable is 1.5.0.

Typeahead 0.10.2 without X-Edtiable works fine.

Answer (score -1):

**TypeaheadJS 0.10.x** is designed for **Bootstrap v3** (Correct me if I'm wrong)
They have changed the way to initialize typeahead so x-editable typehead extension won't work anymore. See the below to see how you init in 2 versions.

*TypeheadJS v0.9.x:

```
$input.typehead(options)
```

*TypeheadJS v0.10.x:
$input.typehead(options, datasets) Check this one here: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

**Quick fix:**
Edit input-ext/typeaheadjs.js

**Change:**

```
this.$input.typeahead(this.options.typeahead);
```

**To:**

```
this.$input.typeahead(this.options.typeahead.options, this.options.typeahead.datasets);
```

Then in when you call it, you can do:

```
$field.editable({
    typehead: { 
        options: { 
        minLength: 3,
        hint: true,
    }, 
    datasets: { 
        source: ....
    } 
});
```

Hope it helps!